# User themes is not showing up in extensions menu in Tweaks

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-tweaks

My Ubuntu version is 20.04 and I installed tweaks through terminal, then in order to use shell i tried searching for user themes in extensions but unfortunately I am unable to find anything except just these 3 options

1. Desktop icons
2. Ubuntu appindicators
3. Ubuntu dock

Here is an image for it

Ubuntu tweaks screenshot
[image: Ubuntu tweaks screenshot]

i hope i can get help asap

Comment: What's the question here? Have you installed other extensions and they aren't showing up? Or are looking for other extensions?

Comment: Actually look at the screenshot im not able to find user themes in extensions panel 
please look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Tweaks"  you will see the extensions that are installed on the system. To install the extension "User Themes", install the official Gnome Shell extension pack:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Comment: i tried the command you sent but it didnt work instead it says invalid operation get

Comment: Sorry, it was erroneous: its either `apt-get`  or `apt`: I have corrected

Comment: {Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell-extensions is already the newest version (3.36.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.}

this is what i got

Comment: Log out then back in, or reboot: User themes is part of that package.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT IS SHOWING RIGHT NOW AFTER REBOOTING
Arigato gozai mas